# How to catch wordpress post ID when it's published

Tags: php, posts, hooks, actions

I am trying to either automatically a forum section when a post is published - like a discussion page. Normally, I wanted to make the users create the topic but I realized a forum category with many other topics under it would be better for discussion.

What I am trying to do is somehow catch the post's id when it is first published, create a forum category linked to that id, and display the link to that forum on post's page. I was plannig to create a separate table in the database for these correspondence but metadata tables might be a better idea, I am not sure. I am using bbPress plugin for forums, Newspaper 11 as theme.

I can't say I fully grasp the whole hooks system on WordPress so I am open to any info right now.

Answer (score 1):

To put it briefly, WordPress hooks let you modify parameters or output of functions (*filters*) or execute custom code when something happens (*actions*). Both types of hooks usually pass one or more arguments to the callback functions that are attached to them.

During a page request WordPress goes through series of steps to get the page rendered. There's a nice summary of the actions that run during a typical request on the old [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). To have your custom code run at the correct step, you need to add the callback to the action or filter before it runs.

WordPress uses [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) to insert and update posts in the database. When looking at the function's source code on [Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L4042), you can see there are bunch of `apply_filter`s  and `do_action`s inside it. The former is for calling the filtering callbacks and the latter for action callbacks.

For example you can see that the last `do_action` is `wp_insert_post` with three parameters - `$post_ID, $post, $update`. You can either read the comments on the source code or have a look at the [action's documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/) to learn more about it.

Basic example how to use an action hook,

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'example_wp_insert_post', 10, 3 ); // hook, callback, priority, # of accepted args
function example_wp_insert_post( int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update ) {

  // is the post new or was this an update?
  if ( $update ) {
    // don't do anything
    return;
  }

  // was the post published?
  if ( 'publish' !== $post->post_status ) {
    // bail
    return;
  }

  // do something with ID and/or post..
  
}
```

One thing to notice is that `wp_insert_post()` returns post ID on success. So if you use it somewhere in your code, then you don't have to bother with hooks - just use the return result directly!

```
// somewhere in your code
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $postarr, $wp_error );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $new_post_id ) ) {
  // do something with the new post's ID
}
```